# Can we produce more negative voltage from a less negative voltage source? (say -8 volts from -3 volts supply)

Tags: voltage, power, negative

I was thinking about the concept of negative voltage when I came across this question. I understand that negative voltage means voltage below a certain threshold, say ground. So, can we use simple voltage division to produce even more negative voltages from an already generated negative voltage?

Forgive me if I'm off target here.

Comment: You need a boost convertor for negative voltages. Simple voltage division will give you less negative voltages, i.e. closer to 0.

Comment: You have two points. You can generate any voltage between those two points with a divider. But you cannot use a divider to get outside the range of those two points.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the positive voltage scenario - you can convert a more positive voltage to a less positive voltage using a voltage divider and the same applies to negative voltages - the bigger negative voltage at the input becomes a smaller negative voltage at the output.

If you want a bigger voltage in magnitude for a smaller input voltage, then you need to use an active circuit that involves energy storage such as in a boost converter.

Answer (score 0):

> can we use simple voltage division to produce even more negative voltages from an already generated negative voltage?

No. a voltage divider basically provides you with the average of two voltage sources. So it needs a more negative voltage source to produce a less negative voltage source.

an oscillator (plus a rectifier) will do what you want. many dc/dc converters (essentially an oscillator + a rectifier) can be configured to provide negative output.